# How to show true progress events with console.log

Tags: jquery, ajax, events, progress, console.log

How can I show real 'onprogress' in the console.log ?
Like in the example below, I want to see in the console : 
1
2
3
...
100%.

What I see is only one value (like '25') after the progress ends.

It's possible (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AZJfXr2LZXg)

```
    xhr.onprogress = function(e) {
        var percentDownloaded = Math.floor(100 * e.loaded / e.total);
        progressBarElem.value = percentDownloaded;
        console.log(percentDownloaded + "% downloaded");
        messageAreaElem.innerHTML = percentDownloaded + "% downloaded";


}
```

Thanks,

Patrick

Answer (score 1):

I use this in one of my projects and it works good for me:

```
        xhr.upload.onprogress = function (e) {
            if (e.lengthComputable) {
                var percentComplete = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
                console.log(percentComplete + "% downloaded");
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, it's xhr.upload.progress.

xhr.progress is using default, which is xhr.download.progress.

When uploading, xhr.progress event is still targeted, I wonder why.